# regex: find new line character in string that isn't in textarea

Tags: php, regex

heya, so I'm looking for a regex that would allow me to basically replace a newline character with whatever (eg. 'xxx'), but only if the newline character isn't within textarea tags.

For example, the following:

```
<strong>abcd
efg</strong>
<textarea>curious
george
</textarea>
<span>happy</span>
```

Would become:

```
<strong>abcdxxxefg</strong>xxx<textarea>curious
geroge
</textarea>xxx<span>happy</span>
```

Anyone have any idea on where I should start? I'm kinda clueless here :(
Thanks for any help possible.

Comment: For completeness' sake, add `<pre>` tags to the same list: Line breaks have a meaning inside that, too.

Comment: I've been dabbling to see if it'd work with lookaround, but so far I've only found the exact opposite: replace EOL's inside of textarea's:

    (?<=<textarea[^>]*?>.*)[\r\n]+(?=.*</textarea>)

you could use this to 'encode' EOL's in textarea's, do the other EOL's, and then restore the encoded EOL's.

Comment: adding above advice:
(?<=<(textarea|pre|code|xmp)[^>]*?>.*)[\r\n]+(?=.*</\1>)

Comment: @Stijn: Those regexes require unrestricted, variable-length lookbehind, which is not supported by PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got it, but you're not gonna like it. ;)

```
$result = preg_replace(
  '~[\r\n]++(?=(?>[^<]++|<(?!/?textarea\b))*+(?!</textarea\b))~',
  'XYZ', $source);
```

After matching a line break, the lookahead scans ahead, consuming any character that's not a left angle bracket, or any left angle bracket that's not the beginning of a `<textarea>` or `</textarea>` tag.  When it runs out of those, the next thing it sees has to be one of those tags or the end of the string.  If it's a `</textarea>` tag, that means the line break was found inside a textarea element, so the match fails, and that line break is not replaced.

I've included an expanded version below, and you can [**see it an action on ideone**](http://ideone.com/He7LM).  You can adapt it to handle those other tags too, if you really want to.  But it sounds to me like what you need is an HTML minimizer (or minifier); there are plenty of those available.

```
  $re=<<<EOT
~
[\r\n]++
(?=
  (?>
    [^<]++            # not left angle brackets, or
  |
    <(?!/?textarea\b) # bracket if not for TA tag (opening or closing)
  )*+
  (?!</textarea\b)    # first TA tag found must be opening, not closing
)
~x
EOT;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to go with regexp, you may try this - escape newlines inside special tags, delete newlines and then unescape:

```
<?php //5.3 syntax here

//Regex matches everything within textarea, pre or code tags
$str = preg_replace_callback('#<(?P<tag>textarea|pre|code)[^>]*?>.*</(?P=tag)>#sim',
    function ($matches) { 
         //and then replaces every newline by some escape sequence
         return str_replace("\n", "%ESCAPED_NEWLINE%", $matches[0]);
    }, $str);
//after all we can safely remove newlines
//and then replace escape sequences by newlines
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "%ESCAPED_NEWLINE%"), array('', "\n"), $str);
```

Comment: i'll give this a go while im waiting for his response above. i was a little confused by it, but when possible, i would prefer to stay away from regex. what's meant by 'state machine'?

Comment: Okay, I've added a few more comments. What exactly confuses you? Google for state machine. Basically you need to iterate over text keeping some _state_, in this case, state is answer to "am I inside textarea tag?". Depending on that state you replace or leave newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex for this? Why not use a very simple state machine to do it? Work through the string looking for opening `<textarea>` tags, and when inside them look for the closing tag instead. When you come across a newline, convert it or not based on whether you're currently inside a `<textarea>` or not.

Comment: could you explain this a little more? maybe with pseudo code? kinda confused by it :(

Comment: Lol. State machine. I smell a college student who just took a logical circuits class. I had one of those last year =) State machine is really hardware terminology. In software terms you'd say it's an iterative (or recursive) loop with a switch or flag.

Comment: I am studying for a PhD in pure mathematics and have never taken a class in electronics or in programming. I referred to it as a "state machine" because that's what I've seen it referred to as before.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is parsing HTML.  You cannot parse HTML with a regular expression.

Comment: You are not quite right. In some general case, yeah, you can't because there is no recursion in php implementation of regexp. But in this particular case you can, because you can't have nested textareas.